# Finding all rows that ends with a folder name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a lot of paths in a SQL Server table like below

```
/Folder1/Folder2/file.doc
/Folder1/Folder2/file2.doc
/Folder1/Folder2/
```

I need to find all rows that is folders. That is after last / there should be something with an extension. Is this possible with SQL or do I need to do some managed code?

Comment: So every string that ends with a /?

Comment: It can also be Folder/Folder1. So after last / there cannot be a dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`reverse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/reverse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) the string and use [`charindex()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on that reversed string to get the position of the first / in the reversed string. If you subtract that position from the length of the string, which you can get with [`len()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), and add one you get the position of the last / in the not reversed string. Now you can use `charindex()` again, this time with the optional third argument giving the position from which the search should start from, to look if there's a . after the last /. If and only if it isn't `charindex()` will return zero. You can filter on that.

```
SELECT nmuloc
       FROM elbat
       WHERE charindex('.', nmuloc, len(nmuloc) - charindex('/', reverse(nmuloc)) + 1) = 0;
```

But be aware, though that implements the logic you explained, it's not guaranteed that it gets all the folders. Folder names can, in general, have dots in them. Unless you're really sure all your folders don't have dots in your name, you might get false negatives.

Comment: This is a nice workaround of SQL Servers' almost complete lack of useful string functions.

Answer (score -1):

simply try with LIKE '%.doc'

on query try to use the last of file extensions or specified the relevant text  probably you will get most successful result as you requested

Comment: In a requirement like this, it wouldn't only be only one .doc extension. It could be any of the tens of file extensions.